# How can I import jQueryStatic from third library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have server running on my client side, with 3 files:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/7.2.2/konva.min.js" integrity="sha512-zbpQ5DaXc34MZEg81DJZSHALTkKr1+eOspsa01J4FSVqhUHjCa/V1xvur7imE4UZcj40uYDIR21MEpxzG2OHvw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" integrity="sha256-lCf+LfUffUxr81+W0ZFpcU0LQyuZ3Bj0F2DQNCxTgSI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='inchlib'></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./inchlib-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
 </html>
```

index.js

```
var inchlib = new InCHlib({"target": "inchlib",
                    "width": 800,
                    "height": 1200,
                    "column_metadata_colors": "RdLrBu",
                    "heatmap_colors": "RdBkGr",
                    "max_percentile": 90,
                    "middle_percentile": 60,
                    "min_percentile": 10,
                    "heatmap_font_color": "white",
                     text: 'biojs'});
inchlib.read_data_from_file(".microarrays.json");
inchlib.draw();
```

And I want to use third library that creates for me a heatmap, for that I am using opensource library that calls InChlib, more information you can find here:
https://www.openscreen.cz/software/inchlib/home/

the file inchlib-1.2.0.js include the all logic of the library and for create heatmap I should init the InChlib object as I did at my Index.js

inchlib-1.2.0.js:

```
var InCHlib;

(function($){
  
  InCHlib = function(settings){
      var self = this;
      self.user_settings = settings;
      self.target_element = $("#" + settings.target);
      self.target_element.css({"position": "relative"});

      /**
      * Default values for the settings
      * @name InCHlib#settings
      */

      self.settings = {
          "target" : "YourOwnDivI
          .
          . 
          . // more code
      }(jQuery));
```

after I run my server `npm run`
I got for some reason this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: InCHlib is not defined
    at Object.parcelRequire.index.js.axios (index.js:4)
    at newRequire (testNpm.e31bb0bc.js:47)
    at testNpm.e31bb0bc.js:81
    at testNpm.e31bb0bc.js:120
```

How can I properly init my InChlib object?

Comment: Not familiar with "node' really but am wondering why your server would have an `index.html` file? Is this how you are doing your dependencies?

Comment: its just for testing. I will build a normal project with good structure after I will resolve this problem

Comment: Ok. What does `InCHlib` resolve to on browser console/dev tools? If it resolves to `null` then you need to re-read the API in question.

Comment: What is *testNpm.e31bb0bc.js*? Are you getting that error in your server logs or on the client side (in the browser console)?